# Direct2D renders in main window but not child window

Tags: debugging, winapi, direct2d

I'm learning how to use Direct2D and DirectWrite.  I wrote a sample application that uses these libraries to render content directly in the main (top-level) window.  It works fine.

Now I'm trying to rewrite the painting code for a child window in another application.  The original code uses GDI and works fine.  But when I convert it to use Direct2D, nothing appears at all (the child window appears black).

I've simplified the painting code down to a simple fill of the client area.

```
LRESULT PlotWnd::OnPaint(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL &) {
    ATL::CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> pD2DFactory;
    HRESULT hr = ::D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pD2DFactory);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    ATL::CComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget> pRT;
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
    hr = pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(/* D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_SOFTWARE */),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hWnd, size), &pRT);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    pRT->BeginDraw();
    pRT->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Beige));
    hr = pRT->EndDraw();
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    ValidateRect(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

All of the Direct2D calls succeed with `S_OK`, so I'm kind of at a loss as to where to look for the problem.  At this point, the only significant difference I can see between my working experiment and this program is that in this one, I'm only using Direct2D in one child window.

So my questions are:  Is there an issue that I'm missing when using Direct2D in a child window?  Any tips for debugging this further?

**Update:**  I've removed statics to avoid confusion.  I'm completely setting up and tearing down Direct2D with each paint.  There is exactly one paint call, with a real size.

If I switch to software rendering (by using `D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_SOFTWARE` in the render target properties), the problem goes away--I get the beige fill as expected.

This led me to suspect my graphics driver, which was out of date.  But I've now updated my graphics driver, and it still fails in the same manner.  What else could cause hardware rendering to fail when software rendering works as expected?

**Update 2**:  I'm still trying to reproduce this is a small, self-contained example.  In the mean time, I noticed that simply starting Spy++ will *sometimes* cause the window to actually render to the screen (one time).

Comment: Have you overridden the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler so it doesn't keep blanking your window?

Comment: @Roger Rowland: Yes, my WM_ERASKBKGND handler does nothing.  If I have it fill with an arbitrary color, then I see that color instead of the beige fill I expect from the Direct2D Clear command.

Comment: Ok, just running through some "obvious" things - does the parent window have the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style set?

Comment: Yes, both ancestors have WS_CLIPCHILDREN (confirmed with Spy++).

Comment: Have you verified that `OnPaint` first gets called with a non-zero size? Just thinking that your `GetClientRect` may be called too soon (e.g. if you create with a dummy size and then move/size the child window).

Comment: The window has a real size on the first call.  If I resize the app, which causes the child control in question to be resized, I get additional calls to OnPaint with the new size, yet the Direct2D fill never works.  If I swap the GDI solution back in, and it continues to work.

Comment: Yes, just seeing that static initialisation in `OnPaint`, you'll never get the new size set after first time through ... that probably needs handling in `WM_SIZE` anyway but may be unrelated to your problem. Any chance of a SSCCE that I can test here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no solution other than to use software rendering.  I'm fairly certain it's a graphics driver bug, specifically, a race condition.

Evidence:

- About one time in ten, it paints fine, so the problem is frequent but intermittent, suggestive of a timing issue.
- The problem happens only with the first paint after launching the application.   (Yes, the size of the window is correct at that point.)  Later repaints work fine.  Fortunately, my application repaints the window every few minutes, so it remains black only for a few minutes after you launch it.  This suggests a timing issue on application start.
- I haven't been able to reproduce with a tiny program, so the problem may be sensitive to the time necessary for the application to initialize.  Perhaps the driver does some asynchronous initialization that doesn't always complete in time to handle the initial paint commands.
- It hasn't happened on other computers I've tried that use different graphics cards.
- When using software rendering, the painting works perfectly every time.  This suggests that the bug isn't in my code.

Counter Evidence:

- Several rounds of driver updates over the past year have not made any difference in the behavior.

I'm posting this as an "answer" because a few others have seen similar symptoms and asked me if I ever found an answer.  I'm still open to reading other ideas and will upvote good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you're supposed to create the factory at application start, and the render target with the window (HWND). Those are not supposed to be "temporary" objects that only live as long as your OnPaint (WM_PAINT) is executing.

Comment: And that's how I started originally, but when it didn't work, I simplified the code down to this to be able to present it all in one place.  It shouldn't make a difference if I create those objects on demand, especially since the paint handler is called just once.  And, in fact, doing it all in the WM_PAINT handler works just fine in the original sample I built (where I use Direct2D to paint the main window).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if releasing HwndRenderTarget causes the painting issues. Quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371461(v=vs.85).aspx : Your application should create render targets once and hold onto them for the life of the application or until the render target's EndDraw method returns the D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET error.

Comment: @vt. I understand that the render target should last the lifetime of the window, but that did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rick's recommendation to convert HWNDRenderTarget to the permanent object I suggest to call [`BeginPaint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-[`EndPaint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or create a local [`CPaintDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d.aspx) object which does it automatically) even if you don't use the `PAINTSTRUCT`. See `MainWindow::OnPaint` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If this doesn't help you can always enable the [Direct2D Debug Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee794277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more debugging info.

Comment: None of the MSDN Direct2D samples use BeginPaint/EndPaint. BeginPaint gets the window DC, sets the clipping region, sends WM_ERASEBKGND, and fills out the PAINTSTUCT.  EndPaint then validates the region.  When using Direct2D, only the validation is important (and I'm doing that).  Nevertheless, I tried modifying the code to use BeginPaint/EndPaint as you suggested, and it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the same factory and pixel format to create the render target for your child window(s) or other [shared] resources.

```
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *hwnd_tgt_main = nullptr;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *hwnd_tgt_child = nullptr;

HWND app_hwnd = nullptr;
HWND child_hwnd = nullptr;

D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES my_goto_render_props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperty();

// render targets and bitmaps and other resources inherit from ID2D1Resource

static bool Create_HWND_Render_Tgt
(
HWND arg_hwnd, 
ID2D1Resource *arg_resource, 
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget **pp_hwnd_tgt, 
ID2D1_SIZE_U *arg_size_overide = nullptr,
D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_NONE arg_pres_opt = D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_NONE,
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES *arg_render_props = &my_goto_render_props
) 
{

bool func_msg_debug = true;
bool func_msg_success = false;

HRESULT hr = S_OK;

// scoped to this function
CComPtr<ID2D1Factory> ccptr_d2d_factory = nullptr; // = nullptr is not necessary

if (arg_resource)
{

hr = arg_resource->GetFactory(&ccptr_d2d_factory);

if (func_msg_debug) { /* using the same d2d factory...*/ }

}
else
{

hr = D2D1CreateFactory(&ccptr_d2d_factory);

if (func_msg_debug) { /* creating a new d2d factory... */ }

}

if (FAILED(hr)) 
{ 

if (fung_msg_bedug) { /* hr error message */ } 

return false;

}

// ommit this line if pp_hwnd_tgt is an external com ptr. releasing com ptrs throws errors
SafeRelease(pp_hwnd_tgt); 

// Resolve the hwnd render target properties here
D2D1_SIZE_U                        local_size = { 512, 512 }; // 512x512x4 = 1MB
D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES local_hwnd_props;
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES      local_render_props = D2D1::RenderTargetPropeties();

local_hwnd_props.hwnd = arg_hwnd;
local_hwnd_props.pixelSize = local_size;
loacl_hwnd_props.presentOptions = arg_pres_opt;
if (arg_size_overide) { local_hwnd_props.pixelSize = *arg_size_overide; }

if (arg_props) { local_render_props = *arg_props; }

hr = ccptr_d2d_factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget
(
&local_hwnd_props,
&local_render_props, 
pp_hwnd_tgt
);

if (FAILED(hr)) 
{

if (fung_msg_bedug) { /* hr error message */ }

return false;
 
}

if (func_msg_success) { /* SUCCESS message */ }

return true;

} // all CComPtrs defined within this function go out of scope and are automatically released 

void Init(HWND arg_hwnd)
{
 

if (!Create_HWND_Render_Tgt(arg_hwnd, nullptr, &hwnd_tgt_main))
{
 /* error message*/

 // end the app
}

app_hwnd = arg_hwnd;

// Create the child hwnd

// use the same factory from the main window's render target to create the new render tgt

if (!Create_HWND_Render_Tgt(child_hwnd, hwnd_tgt_main, &hwnd_tgt_child))
{
/*error message*/
}

}
```